# How to open Android app from Sencha Touch Application and send some data?

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, sencha-touch

I am developing a web app using sencha framework. I need to send some data from my web app to a native android app. Is there any way to do this ?
Can we initiate a broadcast from webapp, so that native android app can listen to it ?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**What you want to do is to start another application and send data to that app this is called deep-linking.**

Here is a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin for doing so: https://github.com/code4jhon/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin

So lets say you have ToDoApp and you want to click a button and open lets say another ST app with the list of to-do tasks of ToDoApp this plugin allow you to do this. (This also applies to open native Android App (you actually start an Activity through the plugin (happy researching)))

So if you have not added Cordova or Phonegap to your ST app it is time, look at this:

http://vimeo.com/76568053

Regards

Comment: Hi..
Thanks.. But I am not using cordova/phonegap is my web app. It is just a plain javascript with sencha touch...No other frameworks are used other than sencha touch..version 1.1.1

Comment: Well for doing what you want you must convert it into a hybrid application you can only get so far with only sencha. Fear nothing Jhon Snow Cordova is not that hard :) Watch the video.